# Add ManyToMany with Spring MVC, JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

In my Spring MVC project, I've made two classes which are connected as ManyToMany like this:

Users(**Id**, balance, last and first name) -> Rentals(**UserID**, **MovieID**) <- Movie(**Id**, title, director and length)

Reading about how to do it, I ended up with this code for both classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users implements Serializable {

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "Rentals",
           joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
           inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id") } )
private Set<Movies> movies = new HashSet<>();

//--------------------------

@Entity
@Table(name = "movies")
public class Movies implements Serializable {

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
            cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, 
            mappedBy = "movies")
private Set<Users> users = new HashSet<>();
```

Not only that, but I added `hibernate.ddl-auto = create` and `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop` to my properties, so that the tables were created automatically and updated in my PostgreSQL database.

The issue comes as this. My MVC has to have the way to create, edit, update and delete any movie, user and rental. I understand that this can be replaced as: Selecting an user, Selecting a movie, adding the movie to the user's set of movies and adding the user to the movie's set of users and saving. The same goes for deleting or editing.

But how do I tackle this in my JSP? Here is how I used to do it when I used a Rentals class, which had the objects of Users and Movie:

```
<form:form action="${addAction}" modelAttribute="rental">
<table><tr><td>
            <form:label path="user.usrid">
                <spring:message text="ID User"/>
            </form:label>
        </td><td>
            <form:select path="user.usrid">
                <form:options items="${listUsers}" itemValue="usrid" itemLabel="fullName"/>
            </form:select>
        </td></tr><tr><td>
            <form:label path="movie.movid">
                <spring:message text="ID Movie"/>
            </form:label>
        </td><td>
            <form:select path="movie.movid">
                <form:options items="${listMovies}" itemValue="movid" itemLabel="title"/>
            </form:select>
        </td></tr>

    <tr><td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="<spring:message text="Add Rental"/>" />
    </td></tr>
</table></form:form>
```

And the controller had these methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rentals", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listRentals(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("rental", new Rentals());
    model.addAttribute("listUsers", this.murService.getUsers());
    model.addAttribute("listMovies", this.murService.getMovies());
    model.addAttribute("listRentals", this.murService.getRentals());
    return "rental";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/rentals/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addRental(@ModelAttribute("rental") Rentals rnt) {

    if (!checkIfExists(rnt)) {
        this.murService.addRental(rnt);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Couldn't be added, rent already exists.");
    }

    return "redirect:/rentals";
}
```

I used a ModelAttribute to a Rentals object, but now that I don't have that class, what does the ModelAttribute should point to? If I'm correct with how I think it could be, how do I send two ModelAttributes, one as Users and one as Movies? Or what's the way to do what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No reason you can't continue to use a `Rental` class, you just have to think more in terms of your database.

1) `User`, `Movie` are entities.

2) `Rental` is part of your view objects.

Did you want to list all rentals? Read your entire database and for each user create a rental for each of the movies. Pass it off to your model. Did you want to create a new rental? Select the user in your rental from the database and add the movie to the set of `movies`.

So, now Rental is part of the view objects and doesn't need to be persisted.

Comment: Exactly as you recommended, I made a Rentals class with just the strings of the user and movie ids, and just created some simple rental objects every time I wanted to add a new rental, just to carry the information of the selected user and movies to the controller. Thanks a lot!